# Convert a sentence from passive voice to active voice

Tags: gratis, library, nlp, command-line

I am looking for a library (Python/interpreted language/Java/C++ is preferred in descending order) or a otherwise program (CLI if possible) that can:

- change the voice of a sentence from passive voice to active voice, e.g. "I am puzzled by the question." would be transformed into "The question puzzles me.".
- for the English language

If possible:

- Windows 7
- free

Comment: One could be build in OpenFST, which is a commandline app. (and i think one has based on this paper: http://ling.umd.edu/~redpony/dyer895.pdf)